How to set different collision filters on compound body parts
I am trying to use a 2D physics engine to model a rotating disc with a pin on its edge. The pin can collide with other objects, either preventing the disc from rotating further, or pushing the other object out of the way. The disc itself doesn't collide with anything (because it is on another plane).

I've struggled to achieve this in Matter.js, which I have not used before. I am open to using other libraries; I picked Matter.js based only on popularity and active development.
First, I set the disc's collisionFilter = { .mask: 0 } and the pin and driven object to collisionFilter: { .category: 1, .mask: 1 }. The disc should not collide with anything, and the pin and driven object should collide.
Then I tried two ways of forming the disc-and-pin:

Creating a compound body with two parts. However, according to this 2017 issue, "Parts can not have their own collisionFilter, only their parents are respected."

Creating two separate bodies, with a stiff constraint between them to fix the relative positions of the disc and pin. This successfully achieves the desired effect that when the disc rotates, the pin moves with it (and vice versa).
However, the issue here is that the pin can still rotate around its center. If the pin is square-shaped it is most obvious.
(Also I'm not sure if this method lets me control the disc's moment of inertia?)


Is this achievable? LLMs are trying to get me to set a beforeUpdate event that cancels out the pin's angular velocity. But my hunch is that what I'm doing shouldn't be so complicated?

Please share your attempts so far. MJS isn't really a physics engine, it's a 2d game physics engine. It does basic 2d game physics well, but isn't generally useful for modeling arbitrary physical phenomena beyond that. So many things that seem easy are entirely impractical with MJS, especially things that involve realism. https://xkcd.com/1425/. Can you provide some context for why you're modeling this in the first place? This will help determine whether MJS is even suitable for whatever you're trying to achieve here.

It is a simulation of the wheel pack of a combination lock. A rotating wheel (i.e., a disc with a pin) connects with and then drives the next wheel.

Understood, but how did you arrive at using MJS as the library? Is this an assignment, casual project...? Can you share the code? if not, it's sort of hard to help. Thanks.

After a few hours I could not determine how to do so with Matter.js. I switched to Planck.js which addresses my two problems with Matter.js:

I can define different collision properties on the fixtures (physical parts) that make up a single body.

I have different types of joints to work with, like WeldJoint and RevoluteJoint, that make it easier to model complex relationships between bodies.


In the following example which can be run on the Playground, I create three disc-and-pin bodies as described in my question to simulate a combination lock's wheel pack. The bodies are stacked concentrically. Each has a pin that connects with a fly (basically, another pin) on the next disc to drive it.
planck.testbed('WheelPack', function(testbed) {
  let pl = planck, Vec2 = pl.Vec2, Transform = pl.Transform;
  let world = new pl.World(Vec2(0, 0)); // no gravity

  // unsure how to disable the mouse in testbed mode
  testbed.mouseForce = 0.01;

  let discRadius = 2;
  let pinSize = 0.2;
  let flySize = 0.2;

  function createWheel(position, angle, index) {
    let discFixture = pl.Circle(discRadius);
    let pinFixture = pl.Box(pinSize, pinSize, Vec2(discRadius - pinSize, 0));
    let flyFixture = pl.Box(flySize, flySize, Vec2(-(discRadius - flySize), 0));

    let wheel = world.createBody({
      type: 'dynamic',
      position: position,
      angle: angle,

      // prevent wheels from spinning when force is removed
      angularDamping: 20,
    });

    wheel.createFixture(discFixture, {
      density: 1,
      filterMaskBits: 0,
    });

    wheel.createFixture(pinFixture, {
      density: 1,
      filterCategoryBits: 1 << index,
      filterMaskBits: 1 << index,
    });

    wheel.createFixture(flyFixture, {
      density: 1,
      filterCategoryBits: 1 << (index + 1),
      filterMaskBits: 1 << (index + 1),
    });


    // Add a revolute joint to fix wheel in place
    world.createJoint(pl.RevoluteJoint({
      enableMotor: false
    }, world.createBody(), wheel, wheel.getPosition()));

    return wheel;
  }

  let wheel1 = createWheel(Vec2(0, 0), 0, 1);
  let wheel2 = createWheel(Vec2(0, 0), Math.PI / 3, 2); // offset by 60 degrees
  let wheel3 = createWheel(Vec2(0, 0), -Math.PI / 3, 3); // offset by -60 degrees

  testbed.step = function() {
    let format = (angle) => ((100 + 50 * angle / Math.PI) % 100).toFixed(1)
    testbed.status('wheel 1', format(wheel1.getAngle()));
    testbed.status('wheel 2', format(wheel2.getAngle()));
    testbed.status('wheel 3', format(wheel3.getAngle()));
    if (testbed.activeKeys.right) {
      wheel3.setAngularVelocity(-2);
    } else if (testbed.activeKeys.left) {
      wheel3.setAngularVelocity(2);
    } else {
        wheel3.setAngularVelocity(0);
    }
  };

  testbed.info('Use arrow keys to rotate wheel 3.');

  return world;
})

Some additional comments:

Adjust the angularDamping of the body to control how quickly the disc decelerates after the pin is no longer being driven.

I use filterMaskBits: 0 to prevent any collision with a given fixture (the disc).

I use filterCategoryBits and filterMaskBits to control which objects are driven by a given pin, to act as though these objects are on different planes.

The RevoluteJoint on the wheel body allows it to rotate around its center point like a pinwheel, without spinning off into space.


